# Can we create Excel Web Addin using .Net Core?

Tags: .net-core, excel-addins

I have an Excel Addin project developed using Web Application (aspx).

I am thinking of migrating the same in .Net core project.

Can we do that?

TIA

Comment: Probably yes, but that totally depends on what kind of API's you're using. Have you got any more information on it? The quickest way to find out would be to create a new .NET core project and copy all of your code into it. Does it compile? :-)

Comment: Ok. I'll try. I guess I can start by adding Program.cs. Also, all the .Net Core 3.1 assemblies

Comment: It doesn't work. Throws assemble errors for below code:
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }

Comment: I will try as per this link:

https://blog.codeinside.eu/2019/01/31/office-addins-with-aspnet-core/